# result returns more than one elements

Tags: java, spring

I am getting an error `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements`
while getting the EmpID

```
Bypass oldBypass = bypassService.getByEmployeeId(employee.getId()); //Causing a problem- Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException' exception.
```

---

ByPassService.java

```
 Bypass getByEmployeeId(Long id);
```

ByPassServiceImpl.java

```
 public Bypass getByEmployeeId(Long id) {
        return bypassRepository.findByEmployeeId(id);
    }
```

```
@Query("select d from Bypass d where d.employee.id = ?1 and d.isDeleted = 0")
  Bypass findByEmployeeId(Long id)
```

This is my select statement.

Should i use the ArrayLists maybe  ???

Comment: it depends. If more employee.id in your case is normal thing then you should use array list, but if it's just an error on database side and you are sure that it should return only one row then statement is good but you need to check your db for constraints

Comment: @FeliksB check your db if there have more records with particular employee id

Comment: @DevThiman i checked my DB , the select statement returns the multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your query returning only one entry? You could run it separately and check its results. Normally the `employee id` should be the **Primary Key** in the `employee` table and that would enforce uniqueness.

If you don't want the `employee id` to be unique among your records, then yes, you should expect a collection of entries.

Comment: i have checked my DB , the select statement returns the multiple rows – so does that mean that i should use ArrayList or what ever List? or should i put employee_id as a unique

Comment: Yes, you either use a List, or add constraints on your table. It all depends on your business logic.